# Style floating table headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been trying to accomplish getting floating table headers to work. Unfortunately I cannot use something like [floatThead jQuery library](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) as I need to hover different rows as you scroll through the table so I've come up with my own solution based on various other SO answers.

However, the problem is that the styling of the floating header does not match the styling of the non-floated header and I'm not sure why that is or the proper way to fix this.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkc4jue1/) illustrating my current code. The issue is that the first floating header which has different columns does not match the sizing of the non-floating header even though they both have percentage widths (that add up to 100%).

The important javascript:

```
var persist = $(".persist-area");
var z_index = 900;
var count = 0;
persist.each(function() {
    var el = $(".persist-thead>tr", this);
    el.before(el.clone()).css({"width": el.width(), "top": "0px", "z-index": "899"}).addClass('floating-thead');
    $(".persist-header", this).each(function() {
        var clone = $(this);
        clone.before(clone.clone()).css({
            "width": clone.width(),
            "top": (0 + el.height()) + "px",
            "z-index": "" + z_index
        }).addClass("floating-header").removeClass("persist-header").attr('id', 'floating-header-' + count);
        z_index++;
        count++;
    });
});
```

and css:

```
.floating-thead,
.floating-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.floating-thead > td,
.floating-header > td {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trouble is the cells in the floating row are `display: inline-block`, which means the whitespace between elements has an effect on the rendered output.

Much more on ways around that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/1241736) (tldr: standard workaround options: remove the whitespace in your markup (easy), don't provide the closing tag (clearly bad practice, potentially risky), or make the font size for the parent element `0` and then specify the correct font size for the cells)

In your case though, you can just make them `display: table-cell` (just like the non-floating rows' cells).

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I needed to also set the width to a px on the scroll event (instead of using `%`) to get everything to line up.